# <ReactNativePickerModule> is showing previous response whereas all the states and values have already changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This a quantity picker modal that will contain the quantities of the corresponding tickets. for that i am using `<ReactNativePickerModule>`. now in the cases where there are multiple tickets being rendered, if click on any quantity picker module, it shows me the quantities of the previous tickets on the first click. if i close the modal and then click on it again, it then shows me the correct quantities but the problem is that the states and variables are already updated to the latest value but still i shows me the previous values.

Code:

```
<TouchableOpacity
                              onPress={() => {
                                const selectedTicketIndex = i;
                                this.setState({ selectedTicketIndex }, () => {
                                  this.pickerRef.current.show();
                                });
                               
                              }}
                              style={{
                                flexDirection: 'row',
                                justifyContent: 'space-between',
                              }}>
                              <Text style={{fontSize: 15}}>
                                {t('qty')}
                              </Text>
                              <Image
                                source={dropDown}
                                style={styles.dropDownIcon}
                              />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                          </View>

                            <ReactNativePickerModule
                              key={this.state.selectedTicketIndex}
                              ref={this.pickerRef}
                              value={this.pickerValue}
                              title={t('qty')}
                              items={getListTicketQuantity([this.state.tickets[this.state.selectedTicketIndex]])
                                .flatMap(({ ticket, quantityList }) => {
                                    return quantityList.map((quantityItem, i) => ({
                                      label: quantityItem.label,
                                      value: JSON.stringify({
                                        quantity: quantityItem.value,
                                        item: JSON.stringify(ticket),
                                      }),
                                    }));
                                })}
                              titleStyle={{ fontSize: 18, color: 'black' }}
                              selectedColor="#1E88E5"
                              confirmButtonDisabledTextStyle={{ color: 'grey' }}
                              onCancel={() => {
                                console.log('Cancelled');
                                
                              }}
                              onValueChange={value => {
                                if (value) {
                                  const { quantity, item } = JSON.parse(value);
                                  this.handleSelectValue(quantity, JSON.parse(item), '');
                                } else {
                                  this.handleSelectValue(0, null, ''); // Set the selected ticket to null or empty value
                                }
                                this.pickerValue = JSON.stringify(value);
                                
                              }} 
                            />
```

[these are the tickets being renderd:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjRAJ.png)
now if i click on the second ticket's quantity, it gives me the first ticket's quantity (previous state), but on the second click it gives me the correct response.